# SQL: How to group rows with the condition that sum of fields is limited to a certain value?

Tags: sql, group-by, sum

This is my table:

```
id  user_id  date          balance
1   1        2016-05-10    10
2   1        2016-05-10    30
3   2        2017-04-24    5
4   2        2017-04-27    10
5   3        2017-11-10    40
```

I want to group the rows by **user_id** and sum the **balance**, but so that the sum is equal or less than 30. Moreover, I need to display the minimum date in the group. It should look like this:

```
id      balance date_start
1-1      10     2016-05-10
1-2      30     2016-05-10
2-1      15     2017-04-24
```

Excuse for my language. Thanks.

Comment: your used dbms name please

Comment: Hi Nikolay, I think there's a logical mistake between table's data and results if grouped sums <= 30 with respect to user_id.

Comment: I am  working with Redshift Database.

Comment: This is a difficult problem to do in SQL.  The solutions that I'm familiar with use recursive CTEs or hierarchical query constructs -- neither of which is available in RedShift.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do so by using group by & having, here is an example of what may solve your case :

```
SELECT id, user_id, SUM(balance) as balance, data_start
FROM your_table
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING SUM(balance) >= 30
AND MIN(date_start)
```

This is a good way to do it with one query, but it is a complex query and you should be careful if using it on a very large tables.